# Regex Matches too much?

Tags: javascript, regex

Not actually too sure what to title this question.
I'm attempting to match only whats between $[( and )] each time.
However the regex I'm using is matching the first $[( and last )] in the entire string instead of each individual occurrence within a string.

Each occurrence could have literally anything around it.
The contents could be even as complex as `$[(("$[username]").substr(1))]`
So the contents should be possible to be anything too.

You can see a demo of this regex here:
https://regex101.com/r/Wr1e6D/1

and the attached screenshot.

[image: Regex 101 Demo]

Comment: Use a non greedy quantifier `\$\[\((.*?)\)]`

Comment: This works as intended, though I notice the ] isn't escaped and doesn't need to be. While the first [ does. Why's this?

Answer (score 0):

If you know that inside the parenthesis will be alphanumeric characters, you use the following:

```
\$\[\(([\w\d]*)\)\]
```